# Phone is bootlooping as I accidentally erased recovery.img

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, boot-loop

I'm using Realme C11 (2020) edition since it was released. I exchanged the stock rom with Pixel Experience. When doing that, I used TWRP to flash the PE. But as PE was officially not available for my phone, I had to use unofficial one from XDA, so I faced many software issue. So I thought to change this again, with PixelPlus UI.

At this time, I again used TWRP to flash PPUI. So, after making flash using .zip file, my phone was booting on recovery mode instead of system, again and again. Then I decided to erase recovery file to ignore the process. So, on pc, I typed `fastboot erase recovery` on cmd followed by `fastboot reboot`.

Now, my phone is bootlooping again and again. I tried to access fastboot mode by pressing volume and power button, but not working. I also tried to shutdown phone, but nothing is happening. It's just bootlooping